# Finitely generated over a ring $S$ and a map $R \to S$ implies finitely generated over $R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, finitely-generated

Let $R, S$ be commutative rings. 
Suppose I have a finitely generated $S$-algebra $A$. 
Let $\phi: R \to S$ be a ring homomorphism. Then does this turn $A$ into a finitely generated $R$-algebra? Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to have that $S$ is a fg algebra over $R$ (via $\phi$). I believe taking $A=S=\mathbb{Q}$ and $R=\mathbb{Z}$ to be a counterexample

Answer (score 1):

Given $R,S$, this is true for all $A$ if and only if $S$ is finitely generated over $R$.

Indeed if it's true for all $A$, then it's true for $A=S$, so $S$ is finitely generated over $R$.

Conversely, if $x_1,...,x_n$ generate $S$ over $R$ and $a_1,...,a_k$ generate $A$ over $S$, then $x_1\cdot 1_A,...,x_n\cdot 1_A, a_1,...,a_k$ generate $A$ over $R$.